# Using value of variable as a name next variable in C++

Tags: c++

I have one question about C++.

I would like to use value of variable as a name of next variable.

Example:

User write value

```
cin>>PlayerName;
```

*//PlayerName = 'John';*

Now app should add +1 to variable "John"

```
John=John+1;
```

How to do that?
Regards

Comment: What does it mean to add `1` to `John`?

Comment: You could use a map where the key is a string. But this has overhead. There is no built-in way to do this in C++.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Comment: Or, probably faster in this case, [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this in C++ (At least not without crazy hackery). What you are trying to do is "reflection" - to edit your program during runtime. This is very easy in Python, but requires shenanigans in C++.

To answer the spirit of your question, which is "How can I programmatically edit things based on user input" is to use a map, as Neil Kirk suggested, where they key is a string.

Then you'd do something like

```
std::map<std::string, int> playerScores;
playerScores["john"] = 0;
cin >> playerName;
playerScores[playerName] += 1;
```

Comment: As a bonus, you don't need the second line : `std::map::operator[]` will initialize a new value to 0 if the key didn't exist.